# How to update a column based on another table value for max and min sequence

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables of below structure. Now i want to generate a report same as table t1 with remarks column with 'Matched' or 'Not matched' value. 
 Condition to select remarks column is, when t1 table max and min SequenceNo column NodeName value for each Ringid is present in t2 then all remarks column value matched else not matched for each ringid set.

table :t1

```
RingID  SequenceNo  NodeName     ISDName    Remarks
1         1          n1           gx1   
1         2          n2           gx2   
1         3          n3           gx1   
1         4          n4           gx3   
2         1          n6           gx1   
2         2          n7           gx3   
2         3          n8           gx5   
2         4          n9           gx6   
2         5          n10          gh6
```

table :t2

```
ID  NodeName
1   n1
2   n4
3   n6
4   n7
```

now only for ring its matched because seq no 1 and 4 th value in t2 table

Comment: Can you add expected result to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use function `first_value` and `case ... when ...` clause:

```
select t1.ringid, sequenceno, nodename, isdname, 
    case when exists (select 1 from table2 where nodename=t1.mn)
          and exists (select 1 from table2 where nodename=t1.mx)
         then 'matched' else 'not matched' 
    end remarks
  from 
    (select table1.*, 
        first_value(nodename) over (partition by ringid order by sequenceno) mn, 
        first_value(nodename) over (partition by ringid order by sequenceno desc) mx 
      from table1) t1
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0545c0/1)</sup>